# Calling a method in a parent class

Tags: c++

After a little bit searching I learned that I could call a parent method like this:

Base class :

```
class Base
{


public:

    Base();
     child *children;  // instance of the child is needed on the base
    float theDelegate(char *arg);
```

Then child class :

```
class child: public Base  //**** problem
{


public:
...
```

But when I am trying to add the `public Base` line, I get an error that he does not know `Base`.

So then I include `base` **to** the `child` , with this :

```
#include "Base.hpp"
```

This time the child can see the parent ,but right when I include the `base` on the `child` I get an error on the parent because **they include each other** .

```
child *children;  - unknown type name child - appear only if I include parent in the child
```

What am I doing wrong here ? How should it be done ?

Comment: Forward declaration?

Comment: concrete answer ? according to questions here it the matter, I did exactly what they show.

Comment: Put class child; at the top of your file of Base

Comment: @Curnelious just comment/guess rather than answer since I'm not 100% sure from your question and can't access a computer right now to test stuff.

Comment: Title is misleading. There's no calling and no method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use forward-declaration:

File Base.hpp:

```
class Child; // forward declaration

class Base {
 public:
    Child* child;
    // whatever
};
```

File Child.hpp:

```
#include "Base.hpp"

class Child : public Base {
    // whatever
};
```

Comment: instead of the include child in the base ?

Comment: @Curnelious yes, instead. Compiler does not have to know anything about `Child`'s realisation since it needs only pointer to `Child` in this translation unit.

Comment: Well this will not work. Doing exactly that will cause more errors

Comment: @Curnelious This is the standard way to solve the problem.  If it i giving you errors you can always ask a new question about those errors.

Comment: Removing the include child will cause error - he will not see then the child and give errors when creating instances of the child/

Comment: @Curnelious In that case, there likely are other problems, which is a topic for another question. These cyclic-includes you told about in a question are definetly dealt with forward-declarations.

Comment: @Anton the errors not on the declaration of the child, but on this : childInstance=new Child(built);  - is that wrong ?  error is :  "alocation of incomplete type Child"

Comment: @Curnelious that changes things a lot, please update the question and provide full, minimal example.

Comment: what does it change? the parent need to create instance of the child , so how would you do that otherwise? instance= new Child() , no ?

Comment: @Curnelious when you construct an object, at least you have to know something about its constructors. That matters. I think you should post another question, because if you will update this one, the meaning will change significantly.

Comment: @Curnelious Forward-declaration and actual declaration are 2 different things. Forward-declarations suffice to _declare_ methods returning the forward-declared types by pointer/reference. Full declaration is needed in order to _implement_ any method that uses the (dereferenced) object itself, including constructing it. Look it up. And if you want a full answer, post the full code, first time, not piecemeal.

Comment: @underscore_d thank you. This is why they called base and child, obviously the Base create an instance of the child. because we are HUMANS and not robots, you get what I am trying to do, so you can help me now instead of sending me to write another question. the goal is for a base function, to create a child instance, then let the child call functions on the base. this is the intention, and maybe I did not put it that way because I am not a robot. So, the only thing I need is to find a way to create an instance of a child and let that child call functions inside the base.

Comment: If I would ask it differently then you would have other complains, it really does not matter how you ask, there are some really bad people here, that attack others, because they do not have life.

Comment: "obviously the Base create an instance of the child" No. The child **is** a Base. Therefore you need an instance of the child, and it inherits the ability to call its base's methods. Just look up basic inheritance. And calm down. No one is attacking you. They are just suggesting that you ask well-defined questions, preferably after having done some basic research.

Comment: child is a child, not a base.

Comment: @Curnelious Search for the _Liskov substitution principle_. Per the language, a Child **is** a Base because it **contains** a Base and can **act as** a Base when passed by reference/pointer to situations that expect a Base. If your Child shouldn't be usable like this, you shouldn't inherit it from Base. And anyway, this is all orthogonal to whatever unknown other errors you're getting, which people quite rightly asked you to provide more info or another question for. As written, assuming the mysterious missing code is OK, there's no evident reason you'd get errors... so it must have a problem.